# wpf border control to span the width of listboxItem

Tags: wpf, listbox, border

Im trying to define a dataTemplate for a business object in my wpf application a collection of which is being bound to a ListBox.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ResizedItemsDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type resizer:ResizeMonitorItem}">
              <Border x:Name="bdr" BorderBrush="Blue" 
                                     BorderThickness="1" 
                                     CornerRadius="2" 
                                     Width="auto"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid Margin="2">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="14"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="14"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SaveAsFileName}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ResizedImageFilePath}"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
             </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">    
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,5" BorderBrush="DarkGray" >
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxResizeItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResizeItems}" BorderThickness="0" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ResizedItemsDataTemplate}">
        </ListBox>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

How can I get the border defined with x:Name=bdr to span the full width of each listbox item? At the moment it only spans the with of the textblocks inside it which dont neccessary fill the full width of the listboxitem and also vary for each listboxitem.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is probably more to do with the ListBoxItems themselves not taking up the full width of the ListBox. Add the `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` attribute to your `ListBox` and see if it stretches the individual items to fill the width.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about that property. Too bad the default value is Left instead of Stretch, which leads to this behavior.

Comment: Disco, knew about that property but still new to WPF and this did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Worked it out. The trick is to set the HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" on your listbox to make its contents stretch the full width rather than fit the contents only.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxResizeItems" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResizeItems}" 
                BorderThickness="0"                                         
                ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ResizedItemsDataTemplate}" >
        </ListBox>
```

Sorry Matt, just got your answer thorugh as I was typing this post.

Answer (score 2):

HorizontalContentAlignment is a nice, clean solution compared to what I was trying. Thanks!

Here's what ALMOST worked, but sometimes made a dialog box animated itself wider and wider forever:

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
```

Comment: Why post an answer that *almost* works when there is a perfectly good solution that do work? Especially 10 month after the question has been answered... (Side-note though: I just did exactly the same approach as you just a moment ago.. :)