# StackPanel - Confine to the width of the parent ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listbox which I want to layout items within. I am struggling with getting a stackpanel to only be as wide as the parent objects. That is, I have a textblock in my listitem which could have a lot of information in, and I want it to wrap or trim (undecided which yet) based on the width of the parent.

The list box item is a DataTemplate, however for the purposes of this post I've copied it as a listboxitem inside the ListBox.

This is all contained within a page.

```
 <Grid>           
        <ListBox Name="ListBoxManageMedia" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,52,10,41" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">        
            <ListBoxItem Height="70" Name="ListBoxItem" PreviewMouseDown="ListBoxItem_OnMouseDown">    
                <StackPanel Height="65" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Name="VideoImage2" Height="65" Width="102"/>    
                        <StackPanel Name="VideoData2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="65">
                            <TextBlock Text="Title" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock TextTrimming="None" Text="long test text about something or nothing to demonstrate the long description issues I'm having. I want this to wraplong test text about something or nothing to demonstrate the long description issues I'm having. I want this to wrap" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="13" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Cat" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                                <Border Width="50"></Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="Status" FontSize="12"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>                   
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBoxItem>    
        </ListBox>     
    </Grid>
```

how can I get my text block (the one with the really long text) to only be as wide as the listbox itself? (which does 'attach' to the edges of the page fine)

[Width of child control should match width of parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101582/width-of-child-control-should-match-width-of-parent-container) I've already tried this SO answer without success, and a number of others like it.

**EDIT:**

Even as a grid my long text just runs on off the page. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 <ListBoxItem Height="70" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,10,0" Name="ListBoxItem" PreviewMouseDown="ListBoxItem_OnMouseDown">
                <Grid Height="65" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="330*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="23"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="23"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Title" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="long test text about something or nothing to demonstrate the long description issues I'm having. I want this to wraplong test text about something or nothing to demonstrate the long description issues I'm having. I want this to wrap" TextWrapping="NoWrap"  FontSize="13" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Cat" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                        <Border Width="50"></Border>
                        <TextBlock Text="Status" FontSize="12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ListBoxItem>
```

Comment: Do you really need a `StackPanel` to layout the items? Would a `Grid` work?

Comment: as I type I'm trying that now, without much success currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it.

This :

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

and converting the StackPanels to DockPanels did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
 Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ListBoxManageMedia}" Grid.Row="1"
DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
Text="long test text about something or nothing to demonstrate the long 
description issues I'm having. I want this to wraplong test text about something 
or nothing to demonstrate the long description issues I'm having. I want this to wrap"
TextWrapping="NoWrap"  FontSize="13" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

If you want the TextBlock to take the width of its parent, you can bind the width like the above, but make sure that its parent say Listbox in this case have its width defined. Similarly for the height. `Height={Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ListBoxManageMedia}`

Comment: Thanks @Jack I didn't thing about binding the width.